# Regex match the text inside NEAR( <match terms> )

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a case where I need to match all the text inside this specific case

```
NEAR(<everything inside>)
```

I came up with this regex but the near search has to be within a double quotes otherwise it wouldn't work: 
 
 `\"(\s+)?near(\s+)?\([^\)]*([\)\""\s]*)[^\)]*\)(\s+)?\"`

Here are a few examples of test cases:

```
near((fred, car),3)
near(("john smith", "(adam eve)"),3)
near(("term 1","term 2","term 3","(term 4)"),5)
near((fred, car),3) OR near(("john smith", "(adam eve)"),3) AND near(("term 1","term 2","term 3","(term 4)"),5)
```

Comment: Do you really need `regex` to solve this problem? If all input data has format `<spaces>near(<spaces><text><spaces>)<spaces>`, then you can solve this problem by using `string` functions like `Substring` and `IndexOf`.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more explicit about the question. 
`<spaces>` is optional and the real search string would be much more complex than this. So the idea is to find the matches `<text>` inside `NEAR` search and replace all the `"` and `()` with some special characters (For my specific use case)

Examples: `((Custodian:(andrea_ring_000_1_1 OR andrew_lewis_000_1_1)   DataSet:Benjamin Folder:"Other Documents")  (Description:a  EDTID:2  Tags:"Tag Parent 1"))  ((DataSet:Benjamin  OR DocumentSets:(aaa AND sdcsadc) )  Tags:"Tag Parent 1" AND NEAR((fred,car),3)`

Comment: Does the problem is that you need to make your `regex` work when `near` expression is not in double quotes?

Comment: @lliar Yes, because the search string might contain multiple `NEAR` which has multiple double quotes or parentheses.

Comment: I think that `regex` is not an appropriate tool to solve this problem. Because using `regex` it is difficult (or impossible) to keep track if parantheses are inside double quotes or not. Therefore it is difficult to find closing parantheses for `near` expression. I think that it is better to write an iterative algorithm that will find `near` and its opening and closing parantheses. Everything between this parantheses will be `<matching text>`. Here is how to find [matching closing parantheses](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-index-closing-bracket-given-opening-bracket-expression/).

Comment: You should extend this algorithm to take into account that some parantheses are inside double quotes and must not be taken into account when searching for matching closing parantheses.

Comment: A language with nesting parentheses is not regular, so basic regex is a very bad tool for parsing it. Using or writing a basic parser that is aware of parentheses and strings is easier, more maintainable and (probably) more efficient as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is if the `near(...)` substring can appear inside a string that is an argument to a keyword. *If we assume it does not appear there, we can use a regex.*

A sample pattern assuming `"` can be escaped with another `"` (SQL-like way):

```cs
near\((?>[^()"]+|"(?:[^"]|"")*"|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)
```

With `"` escaped with a backslash:

```cs
near\((?>[^()"]+|"[^"\\]*(?:\\(?s:.)[^"\\]*)*"|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)
```

See the [regex demo #1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=near%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%22%5D%2B%7C%22%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%22%5D%7C%22%22%29*%22%7C%28%3F%3Cc%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-c%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28c%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29&i=near%28%28fred%2C%20car%29%2C3%29%0D%0Anear%28%28%22john%20smith%22%2C%20%22%28adam%20eve%29%22%29%2C3%29%0D%0Anear%28%28%22term%201%22%2C%22term%202%22%2C%22term%203%22%2C%22%28term%204%29%22%29%2C5%29%0D%0Anear%28%28fred%2C%20car%29%2C3%29%20OR%20near%28%28%22john%20smith%22%2C%20%22%28adam%20eve%29%22%29%2C3%29%20AND%20near%28%28%22term%201%22%2C%22term%202%22%2C%22term%203%22%2C%22%28term%204%29%22%29%2C5%29%0D%0Anear%28%28%22john%20%28smith%22%2C%20%22%28ada%22%22m%29%29%29%20eve%29%22%29%2C3%29%20AND%20...) and [regex demo #2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=near%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%22%5D%2B%7C%22%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*%28%3F%3A%5C%5C%28%3Fs%3A.%29%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*%29*%22%7C%28%3F%3Cc%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-c%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28c%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29&i=near%28%28fred%2C%20car%29%2C3%29%0D%0Anear%28%28%22john%20smith%22%2C%20%22%28adam%20eve%29%22%29%2C3%29%0D%0Anear%28%28%22term%201%22%2C%22term%202%22%2C%22term%203%22%2C%22%28term%204%29%22%29%2C5%29%0D%0Anear%28%28fred%2C%20car%29%2C3%29%20OR%20near%28%28%22john%20smith%22%2C%20%22%28adam%20eve%29%22%29%2C3%29%20AND%20near%28%28%22term%201%22%2C%22term%202%22%2C%22term%203%22%2C%22%28term%204%29%22%29%2C5%29%0D%0Anear%28%28%22john%20%28smith%22%2C%20%22%28ada%5C%22m%29%29%29%20eve%29%22%29%2C3%29%20AND%20...).

**Details**:

- `near\(` - `near(` string
- `(?>[^()"]+|"(?:[^"]|"")*"|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `[^()"]+` - one or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `"(?:[^"]|"")*"` - a `"`, then zero or more chars other than `"` or `""` and then a `"` char
  - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\(?s:.)[^"\\]*)*"` - `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`, then zero or more repetitions of any escaped char and then zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`, and then a `"` char
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<c>)\(` - a value is pushed on the Group "c" stack and `(` is matched
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<-c>)\)` - a value popped from Group "c" stack and `)` is matched afterwards
- `(?(c)(?!))` - fail the match if Group "c" stack is not empty
- `\)`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for